# Keep Travis-CI unique per git branch

Tags: git, github, travis-ci

In the readme for my project, I want to have a Travis-CI badge. I also have multiple branches, and I want to indicate the status of each branch by specifying the branch name in the badge URL. How do I keep these unique per branch? Every time I merge, git will detect that the readme in the other branch has been updated, and now my master is showing the wrong badge (and vice-versa if I'm pulling from master etc.).

If such solution exists, how would I incorporate it into every branch?

Answer (score 0):

A such solution does not exist as far as I know.

Everything you can do with badges is described in Travis doc, here: http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/status-images/

Answer (score 0):

it would be easier to make a gh-pages branch and make a generic html file that displays your badges per branch (though if you are on a private repo this is not wise...)